# Catch doesn't execute Toast

Tags: java, android, try-catch

I want to show a message to the users when they click "Bintro" button and the EditTexts were empty.

I have the next code:

```
Bintro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String eva;
        double por, not;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            try{
                eva = edEva.getText().toString();
                por = Double.parseDouble(edPor.getText().toString());
                not = Double.parseDouble(edNot.getText().toString());
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Faltan datos por introducir", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                return;
            }

//The code continues down here but it's irrelevant to solve the question.
```

My problem is that when I click the button and there is no EditText filled, the 'catch' doesn't execute the Toast message but, however, it returns the app progress out of the onClick method. When they are filled, the app executes the code below 'catch' perfectly.

Hope you can help with my code or with another way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever *shown* a toast message? What happens if you move that line *outside* the catch block? (Hint: the problem doesn't have anything to do with try/catch)

Comment: Yes. I know what was the problem. Just forgot ".show()". My (very) bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're not showing your toast. add:

```
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Faltan datos por introducir", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: S**t... Sorry, I forgot that... It was so easy! Thank you anyway! ;)

Comment: Yes Im triyng but appears a message saying I cant accept an answer in 6 minutes :S... Sorry, I'll come back to mark it!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
  catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Faltan datos por introducir", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using below:

`Toast.makeText(class_name.this, "Message_name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`